# Ubuntu 17.04 battery problems after session of gaming

Tags: power-management, laptop, games, battery

So my current problem is: my battery percentage bottlenecks. I mean i reinstalled ubuntu and everything is fine and charging as usual. But when i game(i unplug charger) my battery drops to say something like 40% and when i quit the game and start charging again my charging stops at 40% and won't go higher. had to reinstall 2 times because of this. Installed tlp and still nothing. Made default settings in bios still nothing. Would apreciate your heal and ideas.

P.S i have acer aspire E15 (e5-575g) non removable battery.